# migrate Flow NFT Execution Failure

Tags: onflow-cadence

i have many problem with my flow wallet (blocto), same error on flowscan...for migrate my NFT's from RaceDay to Dapper. Idea?
transaction: a7892853f4fa8430f9095cefb8031e58055e6599a2a8ea79a22fb2312fedfa18
Execution Failure
[Error Code: 1110] computation exceeds limit (1000)

Answer (score 0):

That transaction is failing because it's exceeding its specified computation limit, possibly because you have more RaceDay NFTs than the application developer designed for.

What service are you using to initiate the transfer? Is this from the RaceDay website? If so, I can flag this issue to their team.

Comment: Yes the transfer failed from their site. Even after adding flows to my wallet.

Comment: I followed the recommendation of another user, namely to add more token flow to my wallet. I was able to display my NFTs on the Blocto wallet and transfer them.